# Why browser hijacker changes the homepage to yahoo

Tags: malware, browser-extensions, browser-hijacking

I have seen many browser hijacker like istartsurf,  ask.com which changes the victim's search engine to yahoo. Why many(almost all)  browser hijacker changes the search engines to yahoo. Is there any thing in yahoo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yahoo redirect virus can also be added to "browser hijacker" and a "potentially unwanted program" categories. Programs that belong to this group are spread using three different techniques:

**Traditional installation method**. You can install Yahoo redirect malware or similar browser hijacker with a help of typical installation technique, which requires going to the official program's website, selecting the program and downloading it to the system. This is a clear example how attentive and careful you have to be while browsing on the Internet and looking for the software that you need.

**Bundling** Yahoo redirect problem can also start interrupting you out of nowhere. In this case, you should know that you were tricked into installing a browser hijacker on your computer in a bundle with other software. Programs that are most frequently involved in the distribution of browser hijackers are various download managers, PDF creators, video streaming software, video recording software and similar free applications.

**Malvertising** There are lots of illegal and legitimate websites that were affected by malvertising. This term means that they were filled with the malicious code that causes the appearance of misleading pop-up ads on these websites. Typically, they offer downloading "needed" updates or promote surveys and contests.

The easiest way to avoid infiltration of the browser hijacker and protect yourself from Yahoo redirecting problem is to install a reliable anti-spyware. If you need a tool that could warn you about the possible infiltration of potentially unwanted programs and viruses, you should choose [spyhunter](http://www.enigmasoftware.com/products/spyhunter/)

This virus is similar to **Google Redirect virus** [wiki](http://www.wiki-security.com/wiki/Parasite/GoogleRedirectVirus/) and **Bing Redirect virus** . As soon as any of these threats gets inside the system, it causes changes on each of web browsers. Settings that are mostly altered by Yahoo redirect virus are the homepage, the default search engine, the new tab page and the bookmark list. In most of the cases, hijackers are capable of altering these settings without being noticed, so you can notice Yahoo redirects at the worst time. Also, this threat starts generating income for its developers by causing altered search results on people's search engines and redirecting them to predetermined websites. Here, we should warn you that after clicking on such ads you can be redirected to a truly malicious website that is used for spreading serious malware.